# Querying subset from angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need to get a subset from a firebase list. Let's say I have two sets:

```
set1 = {
    dog:true,
    cat:true,
    snake:true,
    bull:true
}
```

and

```
set2 = {
    dog:true,
    cat:true
}
```

What I need is to get the "in set1, but not in set2", in this case it would return:

```
setresult = {
    snake:true,
    bull:true
}
```

I tried to achieve this with map:

```
this.setresult = this.af.database.list('/set2/').map((animals) => {
        return animals.map((animal) => {
            if (auth.uid == _user.$key || af.database.object('set2/' + animal.$key) == null) {}
            else {

                return af.database.object('set1/' + animal.$key);
            }
        })
    })
```

But I end up with a list with nulls, and I need only the result set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) operator to compose an observable that emits an object containing the keys/values from `set1` that are not in `set2`:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

let set = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(

    // Combine the latest values from set1 and set2
    // using AngularFire2 object observables.

    this.af.database.object('/set1/'),
    this.af.database.object('/set2/'),

    // Use the operator's project function to emit an
    // object containing the required values.

    (set1, set2) => {
        let result = {};
        Object.keys(set1).forEach((key) => {
            if (!set2[key]) {
                result[key] = set1[key];
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
);

set.subscribe((set) => { console.log(set); });
```

Comment: ,the example works fine, but for some reason I can't render the result to cartant, The view (using ngFor and async pipe) using :
`<li *ngFor="let item of  animallist | async" >{{item.name}}</li>`
I'm getting Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: If the example in the answer works, but you are having problems with showing the result in the view, it would be best if you created another question - that includes the component, the template, and the composed observable. It'll be easier for others to help you. Especially as you've already accepted this answer.

Comment: No worries. Just include the relevant parts. No need for the entire history. If, for some reason, you think the history is important, just include a link to this question along with the relevant code snippets for the new question. Keep it simple and clear and you'll improve your chances of getting a timely and accurate answer.

Comment: if you have the time have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652200/querying-data-from-angularfire2-with-combinelatest), ty again @cartant